# Replace data validation selection in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have list with the full name of the item and a list beside that with the short name of the item.

I would like to create a drop down list whereby it will show the long name, but show only the short name upon selection.

Is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 2):

This will require VBA. Consider this scenario:

[image]

The data validation in column D is fed by the LongList values in column A.

A Worksheet Change Event will act on column D, do a Vlookup to get the short value and replace the value of the current cell. Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim short As String
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D:D")) Is Nothing Then
        short = Application.VLookup(Target.Value, Range("A1:B4"), 2, False)
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target = short
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Right-click the Sheet-tab and select "View Code". Paste the above code into the code window. Adjust cell references to reflect your workbook.